# Doctesting a function that returns different map during every run

Tags: elixir, doctest

Let's say that my function returns a map and some of the value may be randomly generated. I'd like to be able to at least test again output type, or in another words - to check from the doctest level weather returned value is a map. Eventually does it contains specific keys. Is it even possible? The function call may look following:

```
iex> MyApp.function(params, opts)
%{_}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output can't be a pattern, but you can either use `is_map` or the `match?` macro with the pattern `%{}`, both of which will return `true` if the value is a map.

```
iex> is_map MyApp.function(params, opts)
true
iex> match? %{}, MyApp.function(params, opts)
true
```

Comment: Indeed, I guess it should be enough for now. So I can also use `Map.has_key?` to make more check for specific checks. However, it will not look pretty in docs. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, or a pattern, e.g. `match? %{foo: _}, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

While answer by @Dogbert is perfectly correct, it could not be used in all cases. When one needs to check a value that is unpredictable in advance (say, randomly generated,) there is still an ability to do that with `ExUnit`.

Each run of test suite prints out the *Random seed* value as the very last line of test run:

```
Randomized with seed 486290
```

It might be recorded and passed back to [`ExUnit.configure/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#configure/1-options). In such a case, random value returned from the function will be the same (it will not change between different runs.)

This trick won’t work for data, received from third-party services, of course.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Yep, this is a part of the problem - my function is calling 3rd party API and it can return various data for each run with the same params.

Comment: Save for very specific cases, calling third party API is generally not a good idea. One might use mocks, preferably through a dependency injection, to emulate calls to the external resources.